# JsonConvert ends function

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to convert a stringified json object from the front end passed into the middle tier. I'm using NewtonSoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject. I get no errors. But, when I set a breakpoint, I see that the function exits at the call to deserialize. It does not proceed any further. Here's my code.

```
public class tranx
{
    public Transaction transaction { get; set; }
    public List<LineItem> lineItems { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult saveTransaction(string transactionJson)
{
    tranx t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<tranx>(transactionJson);
    foreach (LineItem i in t.lineItems)
    {
        if (i != null)
        {
            Console.Write(i.CategoryID);
        }
    }
     return View();
}
```

NOTE: Transaction and LineItem are also objects I have defined and are accessible.

I'm not sure why the code exits before the foreach loop. Any thoughts?

Here is the json string:

```
{
   "transaction":[
      {
         "entityID":"",
         "date":"2018-05-28"
      }
   ],
   "lineItems":[
      {
         "category":"",
         "subCategory":"",
         "amount":"",
         "tax":0,
         "description":"",
         "miles":"",
         "gallons":""
      },
      {
         "category":"",
         "subCategory":"",
         "amount":"",
         "tax":0,
         "description":"",
         "miles":"",
         "gallons":""
      }
   ]
}
```

Also, I'm not using any custom deserializer.

Comment: Do you have any custom deserializers?

Comment: And could we also get a sample of the JSON text please?

Comment: I strongly suspect that `DeserializeObject` is throwing an exception, but that something else is disguising that. The first thing I'd do is add `if (true) { throw new Exception("Find me!"); }` and check that you can see that exception.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Why the `if (true)`? just the throw should be enough - and simply commenting it out will have the same effect as changing true to false if you don't need it anymore...

Comment: @fredrik: I'd thought there'd be an error due to the rest of the code being unreachable, but it's only a warning in each case. I may be getting confused with Java...

Comment: @DaisyShipton VS2017 at least will detect that `if (true)` will always be entered, and will thus give an unreachable warning regardless. Don't know if it applies to all C# compilers, but it probably does.

Comment: @fredrik: I've just tried it with Java, and there it *does* make a useful difference (to avoid having to change the rest of the method). But in C# it doesn't - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Nathan: Please edit that into the question, rather than just having it as a comment. The fact that `transaction` has an array value whereas `tranx.transaction` is just a single `Transaction` may be the problem though.

Comment: using try-catch with catch(JsonException ex) would help you find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what's actually happening is that an exception like this is being thrown:

> Unhandled Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Transaction' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

This is due to your JSON which specifies the `transaction` property as an array:

> "transaction":[{"entityID":"","date":"2018-05-28"}]

... whereas your `transaction` property is just a single `Transaction`.

Here's sample code to show that - just put your sample JSON in `test.json`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class tranx
{
    public Transaction transaction { get; set; }
    public List<LineItem> lineItems { get; set; }
}

public class LineItem { }
public class Transaction { }

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        tranx t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<tranx>(json);
    }
}
```

So, you have two problems to fix:

- Assuming your JSON is correct, your `tranx` class needs to change so that its `transaction` property is a list or array, e.g.

  ```
  public List<Transaction> transaction { get; set; }
  ```
- You should work out why you weren't able to see the exception. *This is really important.* If exceptions are being thrown and you can't see them, it's going to be very hard to maintain the code. This is actually the first thing I'd fix.

I'd *also* strongly advise you to follow .NET naming conventions, where properties and type names are capitalized. You can use the `[JsonProperty]` attribute to specify how values should be represented in JSON, if that was the reason for the properties being lower case before.

Comment: Thank you. You are absolutely correct. Making sure exceptions are visible is a MUST. It turns out there were two problems. First, as you pointed out, the Transaction property was of the incorrect type. It just so happens that I need it to not be a list. So, I corrected the Json to not pass an array. The second problem, (egg on my face) is that I had a DateTime type property in my Transaction class and there was in fact an InvalidCastException. Also, thanks for the advice on naming conventions.